# Reading characters from file not working as expected due to colon

Tags: c, file, scanf

[Link here](https://onlinegdb.com/SJAFn5CXf)

I have an input file looking like this:

```
1 2 3 4: 0:: 3 4 5
```

I need a simple read and print thing. I am not figuring out exactly how colon behaves. There can be any number of numbers, so `while != EOF` has to stay.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *p = fopen("in", "r");

    char c;

    while ((c = fgetc(p)) != EOF) {
        if (c == ':')
            continue;

        int i;
        fscanf(p, "%d", &i);
        printf("%d, ", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output 1** of the above is:

```
2, 3, 4, 0, 3, 4, 5
```

**Output 2** If I comment the condition, output is:

```
2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5
```

I am looking to find a better explanation of how colon behaves.

**Update**

For output 1, the problem is that I already read the first character inside the  `while c = fgetc(p)`. The below seems to fix this issue, by going back one character.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *p = fopen("in", "r");

    char c;

    while ((c = fgetc(p)) != EOF) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ungetc(c, p);
        if (c == ':')
            continue;
        int i;
        fscanf(p, "%d", &i);
        printf("%d, ", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [no research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) if you are reading character by character, then check if `c` is a colon, if true, then skip that character.

Comment: First thing, the function `int fgetc` does not return `char` so the receiving variable should be `int c`. This follows to `if (c == ':')` where `':'` is also of type `int`, not `char`.

Comment: @WeatherVane That does not influence the problem.

Comment: I just didn't add that, but I already did and still behaves strangely

Comment: It was a comment not an answer. Get the first things right, they may well influence the problem. I have the feeling this question will be like shifting sand. Please post the actual code, you seem undecided what it is.

Comment: The `1` is not read by `fscanf` so does not appear in the output, because it was read by `c = fgetc(p)`

Comment: Single digits? Don't use `fscanf`, just check if `c` is a digit. Longer numbers? Make a mini-state machine.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's correct. Thanks. What about the output when not skipping colon manually?

Comment: @usr2564301 It does complicate things, also I was interested in knowing better the behaviour of colon.

Comment: The colon does not possess any special "behaviour": it is a character. I could tell you why it doesn't work the way you want it to, but it won't improve your skills: this is a debugging question, so the answer is to examine what happens with a debugger, and read the man pages, instead of taking the lazy way. Two suggestions a) don't mix your input methods, b) ***always*** check the return value from the `scanf` family of functions. Because you didn't, the `0` was reported twice.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks. This kind of answer is helpful to me, really.

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip ALL non-digit characters, not just colons. That's because a sequence `": :4"` will cause your code to skip the first colon and then fail to read the `" :4"` as an `int`.

Try this:

```
    while ((c = fgetc(p)) != EOF) {
        if (! isdigit(c))    // skip non-digits
            continue;
        ungetc(c,p);         // put the digit back to the stream
        int i;
        fscanf(p, "%d", &i); // read a number
        printf("%d, ", i);
    }
```